# Как дописывать + вместо %20?

Tags: javascript

При редактирование текста нужно подставлять слово или несколько слов в bb ссылку [url=текст]текст[/url] и когда подставляется несколько слов то естественно есть пробел и то тогда в браузере выходит пробел %20 а нужно чтоб было красиво +, помогите допилять код

например
[https://www.google.com/search?q=Гипоацыдный%20гастрит](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82)

нужно
[https://www.google.com/search?q=Гипоацыдный+гастрит](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82)

```
    var textarea;
var content;

function edToolbar(obj) {
  var path = "bbeditor";
    document.write("<div class=\"bbtoolbar\">");
  
  document.write("<img alt=\"Добавить ссылку\" title=\"Добавить ссылку\" class=\"bbfade\" src=\"" + path + "/images/linkbb.gif\" name=\"btnLink\" onClick=\"doURLbb('" + obj + "')\">");    

        }



function doURLbb(obj)
{
textarea = document.getElementById(obj);
var url = prompt('Введите адрес ссылки URL:','');
var scrollTop = textarea.scrollTop;
var scrollLeft = textarea.scrollLeft;
  
  if (document.selection) 
      {
        textarea.focus();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        
      if(sel.text==""){
          sel.text = '[url]' + url + '[/url]';//[url]ссылка[/url]
          } else {
          sel.text = '[url=' + sel.text + ']' + sel.text + '[/url]';//[url=ссылка]текст[/url]
          }         
  
        //alert(sel.text);
        
      }
   else 
    {
    var len = textarea.value.length;
      var start = textarea.selectionStart;
    var end = textarea.selectionEnd;
      
        var sel = textarea.value.substring(start, end);
    
    if(sel==""){
        var rep = '[url]' + url + '[/url]';
        } else
        {
        var rep = '[url=' + sel + ']' + sel + '[/url]';
        }
      //alert(sel);
      
        textarea.value =  textarea.value.substring(0,start) + rep + textarea.value.substring(end,len);
  
    textarea.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    textarea.scrollLeft = scrollLeft;
  } 
}
```

Comment: *"выходит пробел %20 а нужно чтоб было красиво "* --- зачем? пользователю плевать на это

Comment: Как вариант - заменить в тексте пробелы на `+` и потом делать из этого ссылки...